# Recursive replace in XSL

Tags: php, xml, xslt, dom

I have following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<routes>
    <route name="/path/{id}/{name}">
        <location>~ ^/path/{id}/{name}$</location>
        <methods>
            <method>GET</method>
        </methods>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="id">[a-zA-Z0-9]+</parameter>
            <parameter name="name">[a-z]+</parameter>
        </parameters>
    </route>
</routes>
```

and I would like to get following output:
`~ ^/path/(?<id>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(?<name>[a-z]+)$`

but currently I having output like `~ ^/path/(?<id>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/{name}$~ ^/path/{id}/(?<name>[a-z]+)$` using XSL like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
        version="1.0"
>

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="routes">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="route"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="route">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parameters"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parameters">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parameter"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parameter">
        <xsl:value-of select="php:function('str_replace', concat('{', @name, '}'), concat('(?&lt;', @name, '&gt;', text(), ')'), string(./../../location))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How could I use reuse the result and pass it to the next run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start off by only selecting the first parameter, and then doing the replace using that. If there is a following parameter, you recursively select it, passing the transformed text as a parameter. Otherwise output the current text.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
        version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="routes">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="route"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="route">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parameters"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parameters">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parameter[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parameter">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="string(./../../location)" />
        <xsl:variable name="newText" select="php:function('str_replace', concat('{', @name, '}'), concat('(?&lt;', @name, '&gt;', text(), ')'), $text)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::parameter">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::parameter[1]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$newText" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$newText" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, if you could use XSLT 2.0, you could use `xsl:analyze-string` on the `location` node directly.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:key name="parameters" match="parameter" use="@name" />

    <xsl:template match="routes">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="route" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="route">
        <xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />
        <xsl:analyze-string select="location" regex="\{{([a-z]+)\}}">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('parameters', regex-group(1), $root)" />
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```